# Reactjs, table cell with different background color

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, semantic-ui

in my React application, I have a table (using semantic ui). I want to change `bgcolor` via a condition.
in most examples I see like `bgcolor={(condition)?'red':'blue'}`
but I need to check if the value exists in an array. so if value is in `arrayOne` apply a `bgcolor`, if value is in `arrayTwo` apply another color else no `bgcolor`

I tried this which is wrong

```
                    <Table.Cell
                      key={value}
                      selectable
                      {...arrayOne.includes(value)?{bgcolor="red"}:{}}
                      {...arrayTwo.includes(value)?{bgcolor="blue"}:{}}
                    >
                      {value}
                    </Table.Cell>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `style` instead of `bgcolor` as it is no longer supported in HTML5. Even if you try it without the conditional logic, `bgcolor` will not affect the `<td>`, regardless of React. Per [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_bgcolor.asp):

> The bgcolor attribute of  is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS
>   instead.

Setting `style` property conditionally within the `render()` function. This example uses @OlivierBoissé approach for conditionally setting the value, but you could really use any conditional approach you are comfortable with and ESLint doesn't complain about. You can use CSS `inherit` as a default value when working with `background-color`:

```
// default
let backgroundColor = 'inherit';

if (arrayOne.includes(value)) {
  backgroundColor = 'red';
} else if (arrayTwo.includes(value)) {
  backgroundColor = 'blue';
}

{/* or if you need one color to take precedence when value is in both arrays
if (arrayOne.includes(value)) {
  backgroundColor = 'red';
}
if (arrayTwo.includes(value)) {
  backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
*/}

<Table.Cell
key={value}
selectable
style={{backgroundColor}}
>
  {value}
</Table.Cell>
```

Alternatively you can also use `className` instead of `style`:

```
.foo { background-color: red; }
.bar { background-color: blue; }

let backgroundColor = '';

if (arrayOne.includes(value)) {
  backgroundColor = 'foo';
} else if (arrayTwo.includes(value)) {
  backgroundColor = 'bar';
}

<Table.Cell className={backgroundColor} ...>
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-no3lai) example.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Create a function

```
getColor = (value) => array2.includes(value) ? {bgcolor:'red'} : array1.includes(value) ? {bgcolor:'blue'} : {}
```

And `<Cell {...getColor()} />`

Comment: Thanks but now I get [eslint] Do not nest ternary expressions. (no-nested-ternary)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable and use conditions to determine its value

```
let bgcolor;

if(arrayOne.includes(value)) {
  bgcolor = 'red';
} else if( arrayTwo.includes(value)) {
  bgcolor = 'blue';
}
```

then

```
<Table.Cell
    key={value}
    selectable
    bgcolor={bgcolor}
>
  {value}
</Table.Cell>
```